# Web Camera not working in Chromium based browsers only in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser, webcam, microsoft-edge

I've been having this problem for quite a while now but didn't really pay attention to it, since the camera works just fine with all desktop apps I use.
Now I need to use stuff like MS Teams as a guest and also Google Meet and I can't.

The problem is that the camera doesn't work with any chromium based browser.
I discovered this the hard way, trying out at least 3-4 of them before I figured that I need to also try Firefox and voila it works! But the problem is that with Firefox you don't have access to features like virtual backgrounds, so I really need my camera to start working with Edge or basically any other chromium based browser.

What I've done so far:

- Went through all of the privacy settings in windows and made sure
  that all are turned on - all of them for camera and mic.
- Uninstalled and installed browsers, and even installed one as a standalone -
  still not working there.
- Went into the registry and looked up some values here `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\webcam` but to no avail as there is nothing there on my side.
- Went through all of the recommended settings for Windows 10 in basically all of the articles I could find in the the internet and it still doesn't work.

Basically I tried all variations of everything explained in this article:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/camera-doesn-t-work-in-windows-32adb016-b29c-a928-0073-53d31da0dad5

And also tried different physical device (different camera) which still didn't work.

It seems like there are quite a lot of questions about this same problem in the MS forums, such as those (I tried the resolutions from these as well and they do not work):

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/camera-not-working-in-windows-10-pro-2004/3089abce-1b06-40f4-8e64-7aa44f2fa639
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/camera-working-with-apps-but-not-on-internet/b37ecaed-a2cb-463f-a8bf-71fae7171a64
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/camera-does-not-work-in-browser-based-apps-but/b5c5ac4b-63c5-48b1-be82-37d87df72715

And many more similar posts which are all locked with no real resolution.
It seems there is a major issue that MS does not want to acknowledge.

I will appreciate it highly if someone that had this problem and resolved it can post the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it goes, just after I posted the question here I figured I will start looking in other forums and places and not only for edge on windows but for chrome and the first post I hit had the solution...

Here is the post:

-

And here are the things I did and it started working again:

```
So First please try the  --enable-features=RunVideoCaptureServiceInBrowserProcess thing mentioned above.
Then select the Disable Full Screen Optimizations in the Properties -> Compatibility Tab.
Then Go to Chrome Flags page.
And Disable or Set it to default for this feature -> chrome://flags/#zero-copy-video-capture
And also Disable or Set it to default for this feature -> chrome://flags/#enable-media-foundation-video-capture.
```

One of those fixed it for me, where I set the values to disabled and not default:

```
And Disable or Set it to default for this feature -> chrome://flags/#zero-copy-video-capture
And also Disable or Set it to default for this feature -> chrome://flags/#enable-media-foundation-video-capture
```